# How to make Material UI ExpansionPanel height fill space available

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui

I am working with the [Material UI ExpansionPanel component](https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/) ([Customized expansion panels example](https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/#customized-expansion-panels)). I would like the open panels to fill 100% of the space available.

I have tried using css to set the root.height and root.minHeight fo ExpansionPanel and ExpansionPanelDetails, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
const ExpansionPanel = withStyles({
  root: {
    height:'100%',
    minHeight:'100%',
  }
})(MuiExpansionPanel);

const ExpansionPanelDetails = withStyles({
  root: {
    height:'100%',
    minHeight:'100%',
  }
})(ExpansionPanelDetails);
```

[Here is a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-beaver-u6sfj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to for the ExpansionPanel test.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through `flexGrow: 1`, but expansion panel's parent should have `display: 'flex'` and `flexDirection: 'column'` properties.
You can share a reproducible example in order to get exact answer.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. I have tried that, but not yet managed to get it working. Here is a link to a codesandbox with the ExpansionPanel: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-beaver-u6sfj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark